# How to dispatch tcp request to backends with first byte of content in openresty lua

Tags: tcp, proxy, dispatch, bridge, openresty

I have started a openresty with one tcp server and two backends. The tcp server dispatch the request to backends according to the content from tcp stream. Following is an example of openresty configuration:

```
stream {
  # define a TCP server listening on the port 1234:
  upstream backend1 {
    server  172.17.0.1:8081;
  }
  upstream backend2 {
    server  172.17.0.1:8082;
  }

  server {
    listen 1234;

    content_by_lua_block {
      local sock = ngx.req.socket( true )
      -- reveive first byte
      local data, err = sock:receive( 1 )

      --dispatch two backend1 if data is greater than 'a', otherwise dispatch to backend2
      local a = string.byte(data, 1, 1 )
      if a > 'a' then
        --how to send to backend1
      else
        --how to send to backend2
      end
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to make a bridge between the request and the backend according to the first byte in the request with lua script.

If anyone can help one this?

Answer (score 3):

The question is pretty old, but I hope that my answer is still relevant for you.

```
stream {

  lua_code_cache on;

  init_by_lua_block {
    -- cache package on startup
    require('ngx.balancer')
    -- share backend addresses via global table
    -- (not recommended, only for demo purposes)
    _G.BACKENDS = {
      {'172.17.0.1', 8081},
      {'172.17.0.1', 8082},
    }
  }

  upstream lua_dispatcher {
    # just an invalid address as a placeholder
    server 0.0.0.1:1234;

    balancer_by_lua_block {
      local balancer = require('ngx.balancer')
      local backend_index
      if ngx.ctx.request_first_byte > 'a' then
        backend_index = 1
      else
        backend_index = 2
      end
      local backend_table = _G.BACKENDS[backend_index]
      local ok, err = balancer.set_current_peer(table.unpack(backend_table))
      if not ok then
          ngx.log(ngx.ERR, err)
          ngx.exit(ngx.ERROR)
      end
    }
  }

  # proxy
  server {
    listen 9000;

    proxy_pass lua_dispatcher;

    # cosocket API not available in balancer_by_lua_block,
    # so we read the first byte here and keep it in ngx.ctx table
    preread_by_lua_block {
      local sock = ngx.req.socket()
      local data, err = sock:receive(1)
      if not data then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, err)
        ngx.exit(ngx.ERROR)
      end
      ngx.ctx.request_first_byte = data:sub(1, 1)
    }
  }

  # mock upstream 1
  server {
      listen 172.17.0.1:8081;
      content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.say('first')
      }
  }

  # mock upstream 2
  server {
      listen 172.17.0.1:8082;
      content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.say('second')
      }
  }

}
```

---

```
$ nc -C localhost 9000 <<< '123'
second
$ nc -C localhost 9000 <<< '223'
second
$ nc -C localhost 9000 <<< 'a23'
second
$ nc -C localhost 9000 <<< 'b23'
first
$ nc -C localhost 9000 <<< 'c23'
first
```

Comment: sock:receive(1) will consume the data from the buffer and such consumed data will not be seen by handlers further down the chain. is there anyway to read data without consuming it?  Or add it back to buffer?