# websockets in openresty proxy

Tags: nginx, websocket, reverse-proxy, openresty

I created proxy with MFA using OpenResty, it mainly works ok.

But I have problem with websockets: Firefox says that it "cannot connect with server wss://...". Looking in browser's network panel I can see switching protocols request that seems be ok. My nginx.conf looks as bellow:

```
worker_processes  auto;

env TARGET_APPLICATION_HOST;
env TARGET_APPLICATION_PORT;
env TARGET_USE_SSL;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        
        location / {
            resolver local=on ipv6=off valid=100s;  
            
            content_by_lua_block {
                local http = require "resty.http"
                local httpc = http.new()
                
                httpc:set_timeout(500)                         
                local ok, err = httpc:connect(
                    os.getenv("TARGET_APPLICATION_HOST"),
                    os.getenv("TARGET_APPLICATION_PORT"))

                if not ok then
                    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, err)
                    return
                end

                if os.getenv("TARGET_USE_SSL") == "TRUE" then
                    -- Trigger the SSL handshake
                    session, err = httpc:ssl_handshake(False, server, False)  
                end

                httpc:set_timeout(2000)                         
                httpc:proxy_response(httpc:proxy_request())
                httpc:set_keepalive()                       
            }                   
        }
    }    
}
```

It is simpler version of production proxy, but returns the same error with websockets. I tried to use proxy with pure nginx and it works ok with websockets, but I need capabilites of OpenResty (proxing different hosts basing of cookie value).

Is there any simple mistake in the above file or OpenResty does not have websocket abilities?

Answer (score 1):

[lua-resty-http](https://github.com/ledgetech/lua-resty-http) is a HTTP(S) client libraty, it does not (and probably will not) support the WebSocket protocol.

There is another library for the WebSocket protocol: [lua-resty-websocket](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-websocket). It implements both client and server, so it should be possible to write the proxy using this library.

> I need capabilites of OpenResty (proxing different hosts basing of cookie value)

[ngx.balancer](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md) does exactly what you need, check the [example](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md#http-subsystem) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55250233/9783845).

Comment: Does ngx.balancer support websockets? I did not any info about it on its page.

Comment: `ngx.balancer` doesn't do proxying by itself, it mere an API “that allows you to dynamically select a backend peer to connect to (or retry) on a per-request basis from a list of backend peers which may also be dynamic”. If `ngx_http_proxy_module` supports WebSockets (and [it does](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html)), then it should be possible to use `ngx.balancer` + `proxy_pass` for WebSockets.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it.